# Aliasing two dicts using property decorator-- can a property be made subscriptable?

Tags: python, dictionary, properties, decorator, getter-setter

I would like for c to be a + b.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.b + self.a
    @c.setter
    def c(self, value):
        self.b = value - self.a
        return self.b
```

This works fine.

```
ex = A(1,2)
(ex.b, ex.c) # returns (2,3)
ex.c = 10
(ex.b, ex.c) # returns (9,10)
```

But what if I want b to be a dict?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def c(self, key):
        return self.b[key] + self.a
    @c.setter
    def c(self, key, value):
        self.b[key] = value - self.a
        return self.b[key]
```

It doesn't like that.

```
ex = A(1,{'test' : 2})
(ex.b['test'],ex.c['test']) # TypeError: c() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

I suppose the reason is that ex.c is parsed before it sees the ['test'] part.

How can one avoid this problem?

Answer (score -2):

Try with this:

```
@property
def c(self, key, value=None):
   if value:
       self.b[key] = value - self.a
       return self.b[key]
   else:
       return self.b[key] + self.a
```

python does not allow overload